# Lambda iteration over an Iterator (not an Iterable)

Tags: lambda, iterator, haxe, iterable

I often read it's impossible to call Lambda functions on iterators. And I lived in that belief until now. However reading the book Professional Haxe by Franco Ponticelli and Lee-McColl-Sylvester about what makes an objet an Iterable or an Iterator made me think of one trick, that seems to work; at least in the simple case I just tested.

The trick is simply to declare an iterator() function *inside* the Iterator class, returning *itself* (weird yes, but not that incoherent).

I don't know if this will work in the general case, but this simple examples compiles and works fine on both Haxe 2 and Haxe 3 (http://try.haxe.org/#b764F):

```
using Lambda;

class IntIter2 {
    var min : Int;
    var max : Int;

    public inline function new( min : Int, max : Int ) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public inline function hasNext() { return min < max; }
    public inline function next() { return min++; }

    // here goes the magic/weirdness/abomination
    public function iterator():IntIter2 { return this; }
}

class Test {
    public static function main() {
        var evenNumbers = new IntIter2(3, 10)
            .filter( function (n:Int):Bool return n % 2 == 0 )
            .list()  // unneeded, in fact...
        ; 
        trace(evenNumbers.toString());      
        // list even numbers in the series, ie {4, 6, 8}
    }
}
```

**Why it works** (at least here)

"In the haXe standard library, two very commonly used typedefs are defined: Iterator and Iterable.

Their definition is as follows:

```
typedef Iterator<T> = { 
    function hasNext() : Bool; 
    function next() : T;
}
typedef Iterable<T> = {
    function iterator() : Iterator<T>; 
}
```

" - Haxe Professional by Franco Ponticelli and Lee-McColl-Sylvester

Therefore adding iterator() to an Iterator class makes it Iterable, and usable with Lambda functions. Or is that always so simple?

Comment: **Edit**: my tests suggest it even works with more complex cases (templated iterator classes over templated classes inheriting others etc). Just make sure to write `function iterator():NameOfTheClass {}` and not `function iterator():Iterator<SomeType> {}` and you'll be fine (otherwise in the second case it complains that the iterator has no `Lambda.filter` or whatever other homomorphic method you try `using`).

Answer (score 2):

Check out this (open) issue on the Haxe repository:

[Lambda should support Iterator as well as Iterable #1914](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/1914)

The final comment in the thread is actually what you're suggesting - and it could work, but changing the definition of "Iterator" so that every iterator is itself "iterable" is a breaking change and won't likely be changed during Haxe 3.  Maybe for Haxe 4 :)

The other option is using abstracts, which allow implicit casting, to create a type "Iter" that works with both Iterable and Iterator:

```
abstract Iter<T>(Iterator<T>) from Iterator<T> to Iterator<T> {
  inline function new(it:Iterator<T>)
    this = it;

  @:from static public inline function fromIterable(it:Iterable<T>) {
    return new Iter(it.iterator());
  } 
}
```

I wrote about this in a comment on that issue: https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/1914#issuecomment-19380450

You could use Iter to create your own custom Lambda helper that works with both Iterable and Iterator.

Good luck :)

Comment: I followed your link, that's a great discussion going there. But I really don't understand your solution with `abstract`, with `from Iterator<T> to Iterator<T>`. I guess this is new stuff in Haxe 3. I don't know if that would cause problem during the conversion phase but if not, I think all Iterators should be Iterable. It makes sense to separate the two concepts in a language such as Java, but for a language called Haxe ("hacks"?)  sticking to the orthodox concept of an iterator is just limiting, so I'd advocate for it as well in Haxe 4.

Comment: By the way would it really a breaking change if they all be iterable? Admittedly it would radically transform the concept of what an iterator is, so it's sufficient reason to not do it, but I don't immediately see how it would actually break things (maybe I don't have enough imagination :p).

Comment: The only thing that would break is if you have custom iterators. So if I had a class that matched Iterable<T> now, but then Iterable<T> changes to require an iterator():Iterable<T> function as well, my custom iterator is no longer an iterator.  I don't personally use custom iterators in my code but I'm sure some people do... Other than that it wouldn't really break anything :)

Comment: Jason: Before I tended to see them as not that useful but I recently ported my line drawing function to an iterator, now if I want to detect obstacles in a certain direction for instance for throwing an arrow, I don't need to calculate all the points in the line anymore. So for 2d games with a grid I think custom iterators can be very useful, what's the more if they can be used with Lambda.